# Generating Full Period/Full Cycle Random Numbers or Permutations Similar to LCG but without odd/even

Tags: algorithm, random, numerical-methods

I wish to generate psuedo-random numbers/permutations that 'occupy' a full period or full cycle within a range. Usually an 'Linear Congruential Generator' (LCG) can be used to generate such sequences, using a formula such as:

```
X = (a*Xs+c) Mod R
```

Where Xs is the seed, X is the result, a and c are relatively prime constants and R is the maximum (range).

(By full period/full cycle, I mean that the constants can be chosen so that any X will occur only once in some random/permuted sequence and will be within the range of 0 to R-1 or 1 to R).

LCG almost meets all of my needs. The problem I have with LCG is the non-randomness of the odd/even result, ie: for a seed Xn, the result X will alternate odd/even.

**Questions:**

1. Does anybody know how to create
   something similar that will not
   alternate odd/even?
2. I believe that a 'Compound LCG'
   could be built, but I don't have
   details. Can somebody give an
   example of this CLCG?
3. Are there alternative formulas that
       might meet the details above and
       constraints below?

**Constraints:**

4. I want something based on a simple
   seed-based formula. ie: to get the
   next number, I provide the seed and
   get the next 'random number' in
   the permuted sequence. Specifically,
   I cannot use pre-calculated arrays.
   (See next points)
5. The sequence absolutely has to be 'full period/full cycle'
6. The range R could be several million
   or even 32bit/4 billion.
7. The calculation should not suffer overflow and be efficient/fast, ie: no large exponents or dozens of multiplies/divides.
8. Sequence does not have to be terribly random or secure - I do not need cryptographic randomness (but can use it if viable), just 'good' randomness or apparent randomness, without odd/even sequences.

Any thoughts appreciated - thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Ideally the Range variable may not be an exact power of two, but should work in either case.

Comment: A very similar question was posted yesterday. Perhaps it may interest you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572095/prng-with-adjustable-period/3575618#3575618

Comment: Yes, very similar. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Why have you created the bounty?  What are you looking for that Peter G's solution does not provide.  If you need something more, you should specify it somewhere.

Comment: @Fantius: After revisiting this a number of times I didn't feel that an elegant/simple enough solution was available. And I didn't appreciate the possibility of bit-swapping would yield a solution. Having considered this in detail now, I see that it is a possibility. However, shifting I think is not. The bounty did bring some additional insight (thx @btilly) but I would still like to explore and test other possibilities before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 11):

Trivial solution.  Make a LCG with `R` a prime somewhat larger than the range you want, and both `a` and `c` somewhere random in that range.  If it gives you a number that is larger than you want, iterate again until you are back in range.

The numbers output will not have a particularly simple pattern mod 2, 3, 5, etc up to any prime less than the prime you use.

If the range you want is large then the nearest larger prime will only be a small amount larger, so you'll very rarely need to call it twice.  For example if your desired range is a billion, you can use 1000000007 as your prime, and you'll need to skip an extra number less than 0.000001% of the time.

I found this prime by going to http://primes.utm.edu/curios/includes/primetest.php and putting in numbers until I got a prime.  I was a little lucky.  The odds that `n` ending in `1, 3, 7, 9` are prime are approximately `2.5/log(n)` which out at a billion are about 12%, so I was somewhat lucky to find this number after only 4 tries.  But not that lucky - I found it in 3 tries and on average I should have needed 8.

**EDIT:** This random number generator can have a shorter cycle.  See the note by @dzugaru.

Comment: A small example (x=3x+2 mod 7) concurs, why did the OP encounter even/odd alternation at all?

Comment: @Peter G.: The OP was using R which is even, likely a power of 2.  If R is even you'll get repetition mod(2).

Comment: Thanks, I see now. Somehow my mind I was blocked to work with this simple explanation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Not madly keen on slightly larger prime with possibility of multiple calls to get within range (even thou, in practice, likely unneeded), but will try it and see. Currently I am split between LFSR/Bit Shifting/XORshiftRNG and this. Glad to say that all look like they could solve my issue. +1 Thanks.

Comment: You can't actually do that, cause prime `m` and arbitrary `a` and `c` do not satisfy Hull-Dobell theorem, presumably rule 2. Try a = 2, c = 2, m = 5, the period is m - 1, not m. See this talk https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Linear_congruential_generator#Rules_for_the_maximum_period

Comment: Simplest solution I came up with is take `m` some power of 2 greater than desired range, take `c` odd (relatively prime with `m`) and take `a = 1 (mod 4)`. In worst case you will have to calculate lcg transform twice, if desired range is slightly above previous power of 2, but it should be ok I think.

Comment: @btilly pinging so you will see this

Answer (score 3):

If odd/even alternation is your only problem, leave the state change computation unchanged. Before using each output you can either shift the lower bits out or swap the the bits around.

Edit:

With the bit-swapping (fixed pattern) variant, you will keep generating whole periods.

Pseudo-Code of initial LCG:

```
function rand
   state := update(state)
   return state
```

Pseudo-Code of LCG including swapping:

```
function rand2
   state := update(state) -- unchanged state computation
   return swapped(state)  -- output swapped state
```

Comment: Possible! Simple enough and easy, will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: I think that for achieving randomness just shifting, your shift amount should be itself random. So you'll need two 'decoupled' random generators.

Comment: Not sure if this is wise as I am likely to lose the 'full period' permutation property of the sequence. Generating a full-period sequence is a firm constraint.

Comment: Yes, you would.  Just swap the two halves of the LCG output to form your new outputs, as Peter G suggests.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the first sentence: "state change computation unchanged"? I now see that the bit swapping process will preserve the full cycle property anyway. Thanks for the help +1.

Answer (score 3):

Permuted congruential generators seem to have all the qualities you're looking for:

http://www.pcg-random.org

```
// *Really* minimal PCG32 code / (c) 2014 M.E. O'Neill / pcg-random.org
// Licensed under Apache License 2.0 (NO WARRANTY, etc. see website)

typedef struct { uint64_t state;  uint64_t inc; } pcg32_random_t;

uint32_t pcg32_random_r(pcg32_random_t* rng)
{
    uint64_t oldstate = rng->state;
    // Advance internal state
    rng->state = oldstate * 6364136223846793005ULL + (rng->inc|1);
    // Calculate output function (XSH RR), uses old state for max ILP
    uint32_t xorshifted = ((oldstate >> 18u) ^ oldstate) >> 27u;
    uint32_t rot = oldstate >> 59u;
    return (xorshifted >> rot) | (xorshifted << ((-rot) & 31));
}
```

There are other varieties available at the website, including a C++ implementation intended to work with the `<random>` header (e.g., the distributions), a more complete C implementation, and a Haskell implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy, efficient, and well-understood PRNG is a [Linear Feedback Shift Register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LFSR). Full period is easy to achieve following the steps in the article.

EDIT:

You might consider some of the techniques developed for [Format-Preserving Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_Preserving_Encryption). I believe these can be readily adapted to generate a permutation.

Comment: I have previously considered LFSR or even Fibonacci LFSRs but had discounted for some reason that I forget now. Belisarius answer to the SO question linked here, suggests a way of dealing with Binary Range limitations, so I will take another look. Only thing is, do you know that it deals with Odd/even issue for sure? Other issue is 'lockup' but I think this only really matters if hardware implemented. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @andora Yep ... not Odd-Even regularity for fibonacci (see the wikipedia example linked in my answer to the other question)

Comment: @andorra: possibly you object because the period must of the form 2**n - 1?

Comment: Sort-of: I really want the 'full cycle' property maintained, as I wish to generate a permutation set. Trimming off results to achieve a non-binary range is problematic. For ex: suppose I want to 'permute' 1 to 9, to get say: 5,1,8,2,3,6,9,4,7. With a binary range of 15/16 I have to repeat calls until the result falls within the interval. Not much of a problem here, but for a large range of say 32bit/4bill could potentially be many thousands of calls until the result falls within range.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you do not need cryptographic strength, that does not mean you cannot borrow some ideas from cryptography...  Like the Feistel network (Luby-Rackoff construction).

The [Wikipedia picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher#Construction_details) is pretty clear.

If you pick a simple and fast F -- it does not even need to guarantee unique output -- then you can just feed a sequence (0, 1, 2, ..., 2^n-1) to a few rounds of the Feistel network.  Since the construction is reversible, this guarantees that the output never repeats.

Sample code for 32 bits:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Just some fixed "random" bits... */
union magic {
    double d;
    uint16_t n[4];
};

const union magic bits = { 3.141592653589793238462643383 };

static uint16_t
F(uint16_t k, uint16_t x)
{
    return 12345*x + k;
}

static uint32_t
gen_rand(uint32_t n)
{
    uint16_t left = n >> 16;
    uint16_t right = n & ((1UL << 16) - 1);

    for (unsigned round=0 ; round < 4 ; ++round) {
        const uint16_t next_right = left ^ F(bits.n[round], right);
        const uint16_t next_left = right;
        right = next_right;
        left = next_left;
    }

    return (((uint32_t)left) << 16) + right;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (uint32_t n = 0 ; n < 10 ; ++n) {
        printf("gen_rand(%lu) == %08lx\n", (unsigned long)n,
               (unsigned long)gen_rand(n));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can mess around with the definition of F(), the number of rounds, etc. to suit your taste.  The "full cycle" property is guaranteed no matter what you use there.  In other words, if you have the loop in `main` go from 0 to 2^32-1, each 32-bit integer will occur once and only once, regardless of what you use for F or the number of rounds.

This does not exactly meet your stated requirement, since the input to `gen_rand` is not the "current random number"...  The input is just the next integer.  However, this does allow you to generate any element of the sequence at will (random access).  And it is easy to invert if you really, really want to pass the "current random number" as input.

Pretty easy to adapt to different numbers of bits, although it does require that your R is a power of 2.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Although R is liklely a power of 2, I would prefer the possibility of it not being necessary. I am familiar with this solution but I hesitate to re-engineer it for say a 24 bit number, when other solutions might be simpler to implement. However, the seed 'input' is not a problem and I wouldn't need to invert the process, but realise that I could if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In the following link you can find an example of combined LCG. (Documents and source included) (Note: algorithm is open, but the license of the source is not open (i.e., no derivative code))

http://resource.npl.co.uk/docs/science_technology/scientific_computing/ssfm/documents/wh_rng_version096.zip

You might even try this 7-stage XORshift RNG example:

https://gist.github.com/709285

Comment: Thank you for the help - appreciated.